# Manipulating the received Json Data in Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api

I am passing Json Data from Angular JS Controller. The Json Data contains two strings called name attribute and comment attribute and a list of files. The controller code for angular is given below:

```
app.controller("demoController", function ($scope, $http) {  
    //1. Used to list all selected files  
    $scope.files = [];  

    //2. a simple model that want to pass to Web API along with selected files  
    $scope.jsonData = {  
        name: "Sibnz",  
        comments: "This is a comment"  
    };  
    //3. listen for the file selected event which is raised from directive  
    $scope.$on("seletedFile", function (event, args) {  
        $scope.$apply(function () {  
            //add the file object to the scope's files collection  
            $scope.files.push(args.file);  
        });  
    });  

    //4. Post data and selected files.  
    $scope.save = function () {  
        $http({  
            method: 'POST',  
            url: "http://localhost:51739/PostFileWithData",  
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },  

            transformRequest: function (data) {  
                var formData = new FormData();  
                formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));  
                for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {  
                    formData.append("file" + i, data.files[i]);  
                }  
                return formData;  
            },  
            data: { model: $scope.jsonData, files: $scope.files }  
        }).  
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
            alert("success!");  
        }).  
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
            alert("failed!");  
        });  
    };  
});
```

In the Web API, controller I am receiving the JSON data by using the following code:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("PostFileWithData")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploadfiles");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
            var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);


            var model = result.FormData["jsonData"];

            var g = result.FileData;


            if (model == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            //TODO: Do something with the JSON data.


            //get the posted files
            foreach (var file in result.FileData)
            {
                //TODO: Do something with uploaded file.

                var f = file;

            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "success!");
        }
```

When I debug the code, I find that the JSON data is populating the var model and var g variables. I want to extract the name and comment attributes from the Json Data and store them in the Database. And also want to copy the file into /App_Data/Uploadfiles directory and store the file location in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model in your Web API and deserialize JSON data to this model, you can use **Newtonsoft.Json** NuGet package for that

> `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

```
class DataModel
{  
    public string name { get; set; }  
    public string comments { get; set; }  
}
```

In Web API controller

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel>(request.Form["jsonData"]);

// work with JSON data
model.name
model.comments
```

To work with files

```
// Get the posted files
if (request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        Stream fileStream = request.Files[i].InputStream;
        Byte[] fileBytes = new Byte[stampStream.Length];
        // Do something with uploaded file
        var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploadfiles/");
        string fileName = "image.jpg";
        File.WriteAllBytes(root + fileName, stampBytes);
        // Save only file name to your database
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I save the files in a directory and add the file locations in Database. @Wael

Comment: Still some junk files are storing in App_Data/Uploadfiles @Wael